# Dataframe to RDD Conversion and Coalesce Issues

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am having some logical doubts regarding shuffle and partitions . Lets say I have a Dataframe something like this :

```
DataFrame groupDF = hiveContext.sql("Select col from table group by col");
```

After this I convert this dataframe to javaRDD so that I can do some map operations, something like this :

```
JavaRDD<Row> mappedRDD = groupDF.toJavaRDD().map();
```

When I do this I get a stage called **toJavaRDD**. I am not able to understand why it needs to shuffle , if I don't have a group by this shuffle does not happen.

**Other Scenario:**

After making a dataframe I do a coalesce with some value , lets say 100. When I convert this dataframe to rdd , number of tasks launched at javaRDD stage are not 100. My main intention of doing a coalesce is not decrease partitions and thus tasks. But the coalesce factor is not preserved once I convert it into RDD. This I have observed for repartition also.

```
Dataframe groupDF = hiveContext.sql("Select col from table group by col").coalesce(100);
JavaRDD<Row> coalescedRDD = groupDF.toJavaRDD(); // shuffle happens and tasks are not 100. They are more than 100.
```

Please guide me through this. I am having data in parquet format

**UPDATE** : I understood why shuffle happens. But why I am not able to retain number of partitions when I convert from dataframe to RDD is still a question.

Comment: I think `group by` statement in your sql query cause shuffle not becase of toJavaRDD or coalese.

Comment: My sequence of events is Dataframe , dataframe to RDD conversion , back to dataframe after doing a map operation and then insertInto in hive. I dont do any shuffle operations apart from group in my sql query. If I dont convert my dataframe to RDD , ideally everthing will run in one stage, correct?

Comment: Wrong,  your sequence is just logical plan with final write action. In spark physical plan, `group by` in your statement will cause shuffle in any case.

Comment: Just curious, what are you doing with this `map` function that you can't do with the dataframe API?

Comment: basically i am modifying few values and adding a column in the starting of each row.. do you have any suggestions for this?

Comment: Try hiveContext.setConf("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "100") before selecting it.

Comment: I have already set that value to 2500.. but please let me know what is your understanding on this property and how will it impact